# get unique value from two different multidimensional array

Tags: php

This is my two multidimensional array and i want get unique value and when same iProduct_id's value is occured then subtraction of fTotal_qty. I need help. Thank you in Advance.

This is Array1

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [iProduct_id] => 1
            [fTotal_qty] => 200
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [iProduct_id] => 4
            [fTotal_qty] => 100
        )

)
```

This is Array2

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [iProduct_id] => 1
            [fTotal_qty] => 500
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [iProduct_id] => 2
            [fTotal_qty] => 400
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [iProduct_id] => 6
            [fTotal_qty] => 700
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [iProduct_id] => 4
            [fTotal_qty] => 300
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [iProduct_id] => 5
            [fTotal_qty] => 200
        )

)
```

And i want like this output

```
iProduct_id = 1, fTotal_qty = 300
iProduct_id = 2, fTotal_qty = 400
iProduct_id = 6, fTotal_qty = 700
iProduct_id = 4, fTotal_qty = 200
```

Comment: does the item in Array1 always present in Array2?

Comment: yes some item always present in array2

Comment: @UrvishPatel some item? So there's a possibility that some items in Array1 dont exist in Array2 and vice versa?

Comment: what is the relationship between iproduct_id and fltotal_qty.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use array_map()  function in php

```
array_map(myfunction,array1,array2,array3...)
```

Here myfunction is  the way which will contain logic to do substraction and merging of your items.

array1 , array2 ,array3 are the number of array which may contain your data.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
foreach($array1 as $index => $value) {
  $key = array_search($value['iProduct_id'], $array2);
  if($key) {
    $newArray[$index]['iProduct_id'] = $value['iProduct_id'];
    $newArray[$index]['fTotal_qty'] = $array2[$key]['fTotal_qty'] - $value['fTotal_qty'];
  }
}
$finalArray = array_diff($array2,$newArray);
var_dump(array_merge($finalArray,$newArray));
```

I hope it would be helpful.

Comment: Check this function [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$one =
[
    [
        'id'=>1,
        'amount' => 100
    ],
    [
        'id'=>2,
        'amount' => 200
    ],
];
$two =
[
    [
        'id'=>1,
        'amount' => 700
    ],
    [
        'id'=>2,
        'amount' => 800
    ],
    [
        'id'=>3,
        'amount' => 900
    ],
];

$one_id_amount  = array_column($one, 'amount', 'id');
foreach($result = $two as $k => $v)
    $result[$k]['amount'] -= $one_id_amount[$v['id']] ?? 0;

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
    0 => 
    array (
    'id' => 1,
    'amount' => 600,
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
    'id' => 2,
    'amount' => 600,
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
    'id' => 3,
    'amount' => 900,
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 

$arr1 = array( 
    array('iProduct_id' => 4,'fTotal_qty' => 100),
    array('iProduct_id' => 2,'fTotal_qty' => 100)
);

$arr2 = array(
     array('iProduct_id' => 1,'fTotal_qty' => 500),
     array('iProduct_id' => 2,'fTotal_qty' => 450),
     array('iProduct_id' => 6,'fTotal_qty' => 700),
     array('iProduct_id' => 4,'fTotal_qty' => 300),
     array('iProduct_id' => 5,'fTotal_qty' => 200)
    );

echo "<pre>";
echo "array1 = "; print_r($arr1);
echo "array2 = "; print_r($arr2);

$key = array_column($arr1, 'iProduct_id');

$arraySub = array();
$sub = array();
for ($i=0; $i < count($arr2); $i++) { 

    if (array_search($arr2[$i]['iProduct_id'],$key) != '' || array_search($arr2[$i]['iProduct_id'],$key) == 0)
    {
        $arraySub['val1'] =  array_search($arr2[$i]['iProduct_id'],$key);
        $arraySub['val2'] = $i;
    }
    $sub[] = $arraySub;  
}

foreach ($sub as $value) {
    if ($arr1[$value['val1']]['iProduct_id'] != '' && $arr2[$value['val2']]['iProduct_id']  != '') {
            if ($arr1[$value['val1']]['iProduct_id'] == $arr2[$value['val2']]['iProduct_id'] ) {

                $arr2[$value['val2']]['fTotal_qty'] = abs($arr2[$value['val2']]['fTotal_qty']) - abs($arr1[$value['val1']]['fTotal_qty']);
            }

    }
}

echo "(array1 - array2) = "; print_r($arr2); // your subtrected value has been stored in arr2 

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested answer:

```
<?php 

$Array1 =
[
    [
        'iProduct_id'=>1,
        'fTotal_qty' => 200
    ],
    [
        'iProduct_id'=>4,
        'fTotal_qty' => 100
    ],
];
$Array2 =
[
    [
        'iProduct_id'=>1,
        'fTotal_qty' => 500
    ],
    [
        'iProduct_id'=>2,
        'fTotal_qty' => 400
    ],
    [
        'iProduct_id'=>6,
        'fTotal_qty' => 700
    ],
    [
        'iProduct_id'=>4,
        'fTotal_qty' => 300
    ],
    [
        'iProduct_id'=>5,
        'fTotal_qty' => 200
    ],
];

$one_id_amount  = array_column($Array1, 'fTotal_qty', 'iProduct_id');
foreach($result = $Array2 as $k => $v)
    $result[$k]['fTotal_qty'] -= $one_id_amount[$v['iProduct_id']] ?? 0;

foreach ($result as $line) {
        echo "iProduct_id =" . $line['iProduct_id'] . ", fTotal_qty = " . $line['fTotal_qty'] . "<br>";
    }
```

I hope it would be helpful.